# Obj-C frameworks returns nil, And crashes my Swift Code saying 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using a third-party framework which is written in Obj-C, it has a function :

```
- (NSError *)generateModelForm
```

`If this method is successful it will return nil. If it doesn't return nil, it will return an error which you can check for debugging purposes.`

Now when I call this function in my Swift file using bridging header and doing all required stuffs, it always crash on first line saying 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

My Swift code :

```
if let error = object.generateModelForm()
{
    println("Error : \(error)")
}
else
{
     println("Successfully generated model form, proceed ahead.")
}
```

I had gone through description given on this [link](http://appventure.me/2014/06/13/swift-optionals-made-simple/). But its hardly helping me, since function I am using is a part of a pre-defined framework written in Obj-C.

I tried replacing first line with,

```
let error = object.generateModelForm() as NSError?
let error : NSError? = object.generateModelForm()
```

Also, even if try calling `object.generateModelForm()` directly, without capturing return NSError value, it still crashes.

I am scratching my head from last 2 days with it, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that object isn't nil when you accessing its methods?

Comment: Yeah.. I am pretty sure, because i am using it many times before coming to crashing line.. and even able to use rest of the methods of framework. !!

Comment: Set a breakpoint and confirm that `object` isn't nil. It is the only explanation that makes sense

Comment: @Paulw11 did that, object isnt nil.

Comment: does it crash at 'error = object.generateModelForm()' or inside the if block?

Comment: @Swapnil Luktuke not inside, on same line where i invoke function.

Comment: is 'object' an optional? try object?.generateModelForm()   ...*with a '?' ...

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke it worked. :) Thnxxxx. You can post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 'object' is an optional, try `object?.generateModelForm()` ...with a '?'.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have been using Swift 1.1 you should unwrap when executing that if let

```
if let error = object.generateModelForm()? {
  //do stuff
}
```

Be aware that the if let only lets you do things if the constant variable that you are just creating for the scope inside the if-block is actually an unwrapped existing object. what you were trying to do is set an optional as a not-optional

Swift 1.2 (which is available as of today 9th of April 2015 with Xcode 6.3) you dont need to add that but in case you want to cast it as a NSError

```
if let error = object.generateModelForm() as? NSError {
  //do stuff
}
```